# Updating DataGridView after changing data source during run-time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

```
public void sortAssets(string assetType)
    {
        DataTable newDataTable = new DataTable();
        foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            if ((string)row["assetType"] == assetType)
            {
                string test = (string)row["assetType"];
                newDataTable.ImportRow(row);
            }
        }
        dataGridViewAssets.DataSource = null;
        dataGridViewAssets.DataSource = newDataTable;
        dataGridViewAssets.Refresh();
    }
```

Above is a piece of code extracted from a program I'm working on.
I want to change the data-source to `newDataTable` at runtime. To do that, I have first cleared the the datagridview using `dataGridViewAssets.DataSource = null;`. Then, I changed the data source (`dataGridViewAssets.DataSource = newDataTable;`). At last, I refreshed the datagridview by `dataGridViewAssets.Refresh();`.

However, the visual datagridview does not get updated. Instead, all data in it get erased and remains blank.

What is wrong here and what must be changed?

Comment: Are you sure `newDataTable` actually has data? Also, is there some reason you do not get a “filtered” version of the original `table` as opposed to manually adding the “filtered” rows to a new table?

Comment: As mentioned, you can filter your DataTable to show the rows that match some criteria. -- You could also use a BindingSource as the `.DataSource` of your DGV and use its sorting/filtering capabilities. -- Note that `Refresh()` redraws the control's graphics, it has nothing to do with the data or data bindings. -- In a DataGridView, in case you want to replace a DataTable with another (when actually needed, not here), setting `DataSource = null` is irrelevant: just set the new DataTable.

Comment: Why is your method called sortAsserts when it performs filtering, not sorting? No point setting DataSource to null either

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically need to clone rows, this would be a lot simpler:

```
public void FilterAssets(string assetType) {
  (dataGridViewAssets.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "$[assetType] = '{assetType}'";
}
```

If you've made your DGV based on a bindingsource, it's

```
public void FilterAssets(string assetType) {
  (dataGridViewAssets.DataSource as BindingSource).Filter = "$[assetType] = '{assetType}'";
}
```

Comment: If assetType will contain apostrophes, double them up to escape them